# How can one assign an item contextualized Array to a positional?

Tags: raku, rakudo

In Rakudo Perl 6 `item` or `$` can be used to evaluate an expression in item context. See https://docs.perl6.org/routine/item

I am using a library that returns an item contextualized Array. What is the proper way to remove the contextualization so it may be assigned to a `@` variable?

For example:

```
my @a = $[<a b c>];
dd @a; # Outputs: Array @a = [["a", "b", "c"],]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl being Perl, there's more than one way to do it, such as

```
dd my @ = @$[<a b c>];     # via original array, equivalent to .list
dd my @ = $[<a b c>][];    # via original array, using zen slicing
dd my @ = |$[<a b c>];     # via intermediate Slip, equivalent to .Slip
dd my @ = $[<a b c>].flat; # via intermediate flattening Seq
```

The most clear solution is probably enforcing list context via `@` or `.list`, and I'd avoid the `.flat` call because it has slightly different semantic connotations.

Just as a reminder, note that list assignment is copying, but if you used one of the approaches that just pull out the original array from its scalar container, you could also use binding. However, in that case you wouldn't even need to manually decontainerize as

```
dd my @ := $[<a b c>];
```

also gets you back your array as something list-y.

Comment: Aiui the `$` is automatically stripped (i.e. is redundant) if you bind, i.e. `dd my @ := [<a b c>];` gets the same result as `dd my @ := $[<a b c>];` .

Answer (score 3):

Flatten it:

```
my @a = $[<a b c>].flat;

dd @a; # Array @a = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: alternatives are prefix `|` to slip it into the array (ie `@a = |$[<a b c>]`) or postfix `[]` to get back a decontainerized zen slice (ie `@a = $[<a b c>][]`)

Comment: and of course prefix `@`, d'oh (ie `@a = @$[<a b c>]`)

Comment: @Christoph Great ideas. Why don't you write your own answer with all of those? I'd definitely upvote it.

Comment: [x] done (*Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn*, to make SO happy)